# Limit number of RSS feed items PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss, feed

I have found a nice script for parsing a twitter feed here https://github.com/karlmonson/php-xml-twitter-feed/blob/master/php-xml-twitter-feed.php, however I would need to add a customizable limit as to how many RSS entries are shown (for example 3 or 5). How would I do that and where would I need to insert the line of code?

I have some other PHP scripts which use lines like:

$maxitems = 10;
$items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems);

...but I have no idea of how to combine this with the scripts below.

Any help or tips are much appreciated!

The code from the link looks like this:

Part 1:

```
<?php
// Create the human readable "ago" time for each Tweet
function humanTiming ($time) {

    // Get the current time set to GMT
    $cur_date = strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s O"));

    // Get the time since Tweet was tweeted
    $time = $cur_date - $time;

    // Set the tokens in seconds to calculate which "ago" string to return
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'YEAR',
        2592000 => 'MONTH',
        604800 => 'WEEK',
        86400 => 'DAY',
        3600 => 'HOUR',
        60 => 'MINUTE',
        1 => 'SECOND'
    );

    // Count the seconds and return the "ago" string
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        $returnValue = $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'S':'');
        return $returnValue;
    }

}?>
```

Part 2:

```
<?php
    // Set the feed url. Replace YourTwitterFeed with your Twitter Username
    $feed = simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=YourTwitterFeed');

    echo "<ul>";

    if (isset($feed)) :
        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as text with hyperlinks included.
        foreach ( $feed->channel->item as $tweet ) : 
            // Get the date the Tweet was published
            $pubDate = date(strtotime($tweet->pubDate));
            // Get the text of the Tweet
            $text = htmlspecialchars($tweet->description);
            // Filter each Tweet to make clickable handles and links
            $text = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?(#\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
            $text = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/','<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>',$text);
            $text = preg_replace('/\s+#(\w+)/',' <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>',$text);
            // Get the human readable "ago" time
            $humantime = humanTiming($pubDate);

            // Return each Tweet in a list element
            echo "<li>";
                echo $text;
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<small><i>TWEETED " . $humantime . " AGO</i></small>";
            echo "</li>";

        endforeach; 
    else :
        // Handler for an empty list of Tweets
        echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    endif; 

    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
$maxitems = 10;
foreach ( $feed->channel->item as $i => $tweet ) : 
    if ($i == $maxitems) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Your Common Sense for your quick reply. I tried implementing the solution you gave, however it doesn't seem to work ... anything I am doing wrong? See code below

.....$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=YourTwitterFeed');
echo "<ul>";
if (isset($feed)) : 
$maxitems = 10;
foreach ( $feed->channel->item as $i => $tweet ) : 
if ($i == $maxitems) {
break;
}    
$pubDate = date(strtotime($tweet->pubDate));
..........

Answer (score 0):

If cannot limit when you obtain the data, see [LimitIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php).

```
<?php
foreach ( new LimitIterator($feed->channel->item, 0, 10) as $tweet ) {
    //do stuff
}
```